# Level of Detail and loading map tiles

Tags: terrain, level-of-detail, planet

I'm making some visualization of the Earth. It just should display tiles from services like Google Map (OpenMap for example) on the Earth surface. This services provide Earth satellite image textures of different parts of Earth at different zoom levels (resolution). The goal is make something similar with Google Earth.

Of course I want to load only visible tiles at appropriate zoom level depending on distance to the camera center. So I'm interesting in how to decide which tiles on which levels should I load depending on current camera position.

I know how to find region on the Earth surface that currently visible depending on camera view and projection matrix. And I can calculate the desired resolution (zoom level) of tiles for each point inside this region. Now, how to find out tile coordinates and zooms that I need to download form OpenMap or similar services? Is there some algorithm to do it?